# Errors occurred when EMQ started after adding plug-ins: You've tried to set XXX, but there is no set with that name

Tags: erlang, emq

I use emqttd-windows 10-v2.3.11

I want to load custom plug-ins in EMQTT.

I placed the plug-in file under the EMQTT\emqttd-windows10-v2.3.11\emqttd\lib directory and the configuration file under the EMQTT\emqttd-windows 10-v2.3.11\emqttd\etc\plugins directory.

The following error occurred when the command ". binemqttd console" was executed in CMD to start EMQ. Errors may mean that EMQTT cannot find new variables in the plug-in.

```
D:\softwareBag\EMQTT\emqttd-windows10-v2.3.11\emqttd>.\bin\emqttd console
21:47:46.858 [error] You've tried to set wunaozai.auth.redis.server, but there is no setting with that name.
21:47:46.858 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
21:47:46.906 [error]     auth.redis.server
21:47:46.906 [error]     auth.ldap.servers
21:47:46.906 [error]     auth.mongo.server
21:47:46.906 [error] You've tried to set wunaozai.auth.redis.pool, but there is no setting with that name.
21:47:46.906 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
21:47:46.948 [error]     auth.redis.pool
21:47:46.948 [error]     auth.mongo.pool
21:47:46.948 [error]     auth.mysql.pool
21:47:46.949 [error] You've tried to set wunaozai.auth.redis.database, but there is no setting with that name.
21:47:46.949 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
21:47:46.994 [error]     auth.redis.database
21:47:46.994 [error]     auth.mongo.database
21:47:46.994 [error]     auth.mysql.database
21:47:46.995 [error] You've tried to set wunaozai.auth.redis.auth_cmd, but there is no setting with that name.
21:47:46.995 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
21:47:47.056 [error]     auth.redis.auth_cmd
21:47:47.056 [error]     auth.redis.acl_cmd
21:47:47.056 [error]     auth.redis.super_cmd
21:47:47.056 [error] You've tried to set wunaozai.auth.redis.password_hash, but there is no setting with that name.
21:47:47.057 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
21:47:47.130 [error]     auth.redis.password_hash
21:47:47.130 [error]     auth.ldap.password_hash
21:47:47.130 [error]     auth.mongo.auth_query.password_hash
21:47:47.130 [error] You've tried to set wunaozai.auth.redis.super_cmd, but there is no setting with that name.
21:47:47.130 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
21:47:47.202 [error]     auth.redis.super_cmd
21:47:47.202 [error]     auth.redis.auth_cmd
21:47:47.202 [error]     auth.redis.acl_cmd
21:47:47.202 [error] You've tried to set wunaozai.auth.redis.acl_cmd, but there is no setting with that name.
21:47:47.202 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
21:47:47.266 [error]     auth.redis.acl_cmd
21:47:47.266 [error]     auth.redis.auth_cmd
21:47:47.266 [error]     auth.redis.super_cmd
21:47:47.267 [error] You've tried to set wunaozai.msg.kafka.server, but there is no setting with that name.
21:47:47.267 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
21:47:47.328 [error]     auth.mongo.server
21:47:47.328 [error]     auth.mysql.server
21:47:47.328 [error]     auth.pgsql.server
21:47:47.336 [error] Error generating configuration in phase transform_datatypes
21:47:47.336 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: wunaozai.msg.kafka.server
21:47:47.336 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: wunaozai.auth.redis.acl_cmd
21:47:47.336 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: wunaozai.auth.redis.super_cmd
21:47:47.336 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: wunaozai.auth.redis.password_hash
21:47:47.336 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: wunaozai.auth.redis.auth_cmd
21:47:47.336 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: wunaozai.auth.redis.database
21:47:47.336 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: wunaozai.auth.redis.pool
21:47:47.336 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: wunaozai.auth.redis.server
```

I have consulted EMQTT customer service staff, they said that the plug-in configuration file and configuration file parsing file schema is wrong, but I don't know what is wrong.

### The following is the content of my plug-in configuration file (.conf)

```
## redis config
wunaozai.auth.redis.server = 127.0.0.1:6379
wunaozai.auth.redis.pool = 8
wunaozai.auth.redis.database = 0
##wunaozai.auth.redis.password =
wunaozai.auth.redis.auth_cmd = HMGET mqtt_user:%u password
wunaozai.auth.redis.password_hash = plain
wunaozai.auth.redis.super_cmd = HGET mqtt_user:%u is_superuser
wunaozai.auth.redis.acl_cmd = HGETALL mqtt_acl:%u
## kafka config
wunaozai.msg.kafka.server = 127.0.0.1:9092
##wunaozai.msg.kafka.topic = test
```

### The following is the content of my plug-in configuration file parsing file (. schema)

```
%% emq_auth_pgsl config mapping

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.server", "emq_auth_pgsql.server", [
  {default, {"127.0.0.1", 5432}},
  {datatype, [integer, ip, string]}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.pool", "emq_auth_pgsql.server", [
  {default, 8},
  {datatype, integer}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.database", "emq_auth_pgsql.server", [
  {datatype, string}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.username", "emq_auth_pgsql.server", [
  {default, ""},
  {datatype, string}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.password", "emq_auth_pgsql.server", [
  {default, ""},
  {datatype, string}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.encoding", "emq_auth_pgsql.server", [
  {default, utf8},
  {datatype, atom}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.ssl", "emq_auth_pgsql.server", [
  {default, false},
  {datatype, {enum, [true, false]}}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.ssl_opts.keyfile", "emq_auth_pgsql.server", [
  {datatype, string}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.ssl_opts.certfile", "emq_auth_pgsql.server", [
  {datatype, string}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.ssl_opts.cacertfile", "emq_auth_pgsql.server", [
  {datatype, string}
]}.

{translation, "emq_auth_pgsql.server", fun(Conf) ->
  {PgHost, PgPort} =
  case cuttlefish:conf_get("auth.pgsql.server", Conf) of
    {Ip, Port} -> {Ip, Port};
    S          -> case string:tokens(S, ":") of
                    [Domain]       -> {Domain, 5432};
                    [Domain, Port] -> {Domain, list_to_integer(Port)}
                  end
    end,
  Pool = cuttlefish:conf_get("auth.pgsql.pool", Conf),
  Username = cuttlefish:conf_get("auth.pgsql.username", Conf),
  Passwd = cuttlefish:conf_get("auth.pgsql.password", Conf, ""),
  DB = cuttlefish:conf_get("auth.pgsql.database", Conf),
  Encoding = cuttlefish:conf_get("auth.pgsql.encoding", Conf),
  Ssl = cuttlefish:conf_get("auth.pgsql.ssl", Conf),

  Filter  = fun(Opts) -> [{K, V} || {K, V} <- Opts, V =/= undefined] end,
  SslOpts = fun(Prefix) ->
                Filter([{keyfile,    cuttlefish:conf_get(Prefix ++ ".keyfile", Conf, undefined)},
                        {certfile,   cuttlefish:conf_get(Prefix ++ ".certfile", Conf, undefined)},
                        {cacertfile, cuttlefish:conf_get(Prefix ++ ".cacertfile", Conf, undefined)}])
            end,
  [{pool_size, Pool},
   {auto_reconnect, 1},
   {host, PgHost},
   {port, PgPort},
   {username, Username},
   {password, Passwd},
   {database, DB},
   {encoding, Encoding},
   {ssl, Ssl},
   {ssl_opts, SslOpts("auth.pgsql.ssl_opts")}]
end}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.auth_query", "emq_auth_pgsql.auth_query", [
  {datatype, string}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.password_hash", "emq_auth_pgsql.password_hash", [
  {datatype, string}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.pbkdf2_macfun", "emq_auth_pgsql.pbkdf2_macfun", [
  {datatype, atom}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.pbkdf2_iterations", "emq_auth_pgsql.pbkdf2_iterations", [
  {datatype, integer}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.pbkdf2_dklen", "emq_auth_pgsql.pbkdf2_dklen", [
  {datatype, integer}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.super_query", "emq_auth_pgsql.super_query", [
  {datatype, string}
]}.

{mapping, "auth.pgsql.acl_query", "emq_auth_pgsql.acl_query", [
  {datatype, string}
]}.

{translation, "emq_auth_pgsql.password_hash", fun(Conf) ->
  HashValue = cuttlefish:conf_get("auth.pgsql.password_hash", Conf),
  case string:tokens(HashValue, ",") of
    [Hash]           -> list_to_atom(Hash);
    [Prefix, Suffix] -> {list_to_atom(Prefix), list_to_atom(Suffix)};
    [Hash, MacFun, Iterations, Dklen] -> {list_to_atom(Hash), list_to_atom(MacFun), list_to_integer(Iterations), list_to_integer(Dklen)};
    _                -> plain
  end
end}.
```

The full code of the plug-in: https://files.cnblogs.com/files/wunaozai/emq_plugin_wunaozai.zip

I hope the plug-in loads correctly when executing the command ".\bin\emqttd console"

Answer (score 0):

There should be an entry `wunaozai.auth.redis.server` in your .schema file.

POST such questions at https://github.com/emqx/emqx/issues would be answered faster.